# Why doesn't this logging setup work?

Tags: python, logging

I have the following code in my `__init__.py` which sets up my logger for my python package:

```
import logging
import logging.config
global LOG_FILENAME
LOG_CONFIG_FILE=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
                             'logging_config.conf')
if os.path.isfile(LOG_CONFIG_FILE)!=True:
    raise Exception
logging.config.fileConfig(LOG_CONFIG_FILE,disable_existing_loggers=False)

LOG=logging.getLogger('root')
LOG.info('Initializing PyCoTools')
LOG.info('Initializing Logging System')
LOG.info('logging config file at: {}'.format(LOG_CONFIG_FILE))
```

In the same directory as `__init__.py` I have a logging config file called `logging_config.conf` with the following content:

```
[formatters]
keys: simple,custom,custom2

[handlers]
keys: console,fh,rotatingfh

[loggers]
keys: root,pycopi,PEAnalysis,pydentify2

[logger_root]
level: DEBUG
handlers: rotatingfh,console
qualname=root
propagate=0

[logger_pycopi]
level: DEBUG
handlers: rotatingfh,console
qualname=pycopi
propagate=0

[logger_PEAnalysis]
level: DEBUG
handlers: rotatingfh,console
qualname=PEAnalysis
propagate=0

[logger_pydentify2]
level: DEBUG
handlers: rotatingfh,console
qualname=pydentify2
propagate=0


[handler_console]
class: logging.StreamHandler
args: (sys.stdout,)
formatter: custom2
level: DEBUG

[handler_fh]
class: logging.FileHandler
args: ('log.log','a')
formatter: custom2
level=DEBUG

[handler_rotatingfh]
class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
args: ('log.log',100000,2)
formatter: custom2
level=DEBUG

[formatter_simple]
format: %(name)s:%(levelname)s:  %(message)s

[formatter_custom]
format: %(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(filename)s:%(funcName)s:%(message)s

[formatter_custom2]
format: %(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(module)s:%(lineno)d:%(message)s
```

Then in each python module (such as `pycopi.py`) I have:

```
LOG=logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

So I can start logging in each file like:

```
LOG.debug('Debugging my code')
```

This was working as expected (i.e. log to both console and to a file at level debug) earlier today but without knowingly changing anything, this logger no longer actually does any logging. Can anybody spot the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that because I was using the logging system 'intra' package, i.e. I was logging things whilst developing a package, the `__init__.py` file wasn't being called automatically like it would do if I was using the package from `import`. Therefore the logging setup code wasn't being used and no logging. The solution isn't very elegant but its to manually run the `__init__.py` file for each python session.